# Тире/двоеточие: Имя(:/-) Иван... Место(:/-) парк

Tags: пунктуация

1)В данном случае правильно ставить двоеточие или тире?
Имя: Иван
Фамилия: Петров
Образование: МГУ
Степень: Первая
и т. д.
2) Встречаемся в 12:00. Место: Парк

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если информация представлена по типу анкетных данных, правильно ставить двоеточие. В данном случае двоеточие - технический знак, а не пунктуационный. Обратите внимание на то, что после двоеточия текст пишется с маленькой буквы, если это не имя или аббревиатура.

Имя: Иван.

Фамилия: Петров.

Образование: МГУ.

Степень: первая.

Место: парк.